# Linking wasmer with Zig 0.12.0-dev.1390+94cee4fb2

Tags: windows, zig

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I'm trying to see if I can link/use wasmer in my Zig project.

Zig Version: 0.12.0-dev.1390+94cee4fb2

Results when when I use  "https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer/releases/download/v4.2.3/wasmer-windows-gnu64.tar.gz":

```
$ zig build
zig build-exe map-editor Debug native: error: error(link): DLL import library for -lwasmer-headless not found
error: DllImportLibraryNotFound

zig build-exe map-editor Debug native: error: the following command exited with error code 1:
C:\zig\current\zig.exe build-exe D:\ZigProjects\map-editor\src\main.zig D:\ZigProjects\map-editor\zig-cache\o\9ab7a8da798fd3955a091a2fa5ef689e\SDL2.lib -lsetupapi -lwinmm -lgdi32 -limm32 -lversion -loleaut32 -lole32 -lwasmer-headless -lc --cache-dir D:\ZigProjects\map-editor\zig-cache --global-cache-dir C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\zig --name map-editor -I D:\ZigProjects\map-editor\zig-cache\i\518fa4a1e1b590ff4b0963ed0d3f4703\include -I C:\Program Files (x86)\Wasmer\include -L C:\Program Files (x86)\Wasmer\lib --listen=-
```

Results when when I use "https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer/releases/download/v4.2.3/wasmer-windows-amd64.tar.gz"

```
$ zig build
zig build-exe map-editor Debug native: error: the following command failed with 2 compilation errors:
C:\zig\current\zig.exe build-exe D:\ZigProjects\map-editor\src\main.zig D:\ZigProjects\map-editor\zig-cache\o\9ab7a8da798fd3955a091a2fa5ef689e\SDL2.lib -lsetupapi -lwinmm -lgdi32 -limm32 -lversion -loleaut32 -lole32 -lwasmer-headless -lc --cache-dir D:\ZigProjects\map-editor\zig-cache --global-cache-dir C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\zig --name map-editor -I D:\ZigProjects\map-editor\zig-cache\i\518fa4a1e1b590ff4b0963ed0d3f4703\include -I C:\Program Files (x86)\Wasmer\include -L C:\Program Files (x86)\Wasmer\lib --listen=-
Build Summary: 2/5 steps succeeded; 1 failed (disable with --summary none)
install transitive failure
└─ install map-editor transitive failure
   └─ zig build-exe map-editor Debug native 2 errors
error: lld-link: could not open 'libMSVCRT.a': No such file or directory
error: lld-link: could not open 'libOLDNAMES.a': No such file or directory
```

Cutdown version of build.zig

```c
pub fn build(b: *Builder) !void {
    const maybe_wasmer_lib_dir = detectWasmerLibDir(b);
    if (maybe_wasmer_lib_dir) |wasmer_lib_dir| {
        exe.addRPath(.{ .path = wasmer_lib_dir }); // Not sure what this is needed for?
        exe.addLibraryPath(.{ .path = wasmer_lib_dir });
        exe.linkSystemLibrary("wasmer-headless");
        const maybe_wasmer_include_dir = detectWasmerIncludeDir(b);
        if (maybe_wasmer_include_dir) |wasmer_include_dir| {
            exe.addIncludePath(.{ .path = wasmer_include_dir });
        } else {
            return error.WasmerMissingIncludePath;
        }
    } else {
        return error.WasmerNotInstalledInPath;
    }
}

fn detectWasmerLibDir(b: *std.build.Builder) ?[]const u8 {
    const argv = &[_][]const u8{ "wasmer", "config", "--libdir" };
    const result = std.ChildProcess.run(.{
        .allocator = b.allocator,
        .argv = argv,
    }) catch return null;

    if (result.stderr.len != 0 or result.term.Exited != 0) return null;

    const lib_dir = std.mem.trimRight(u8, result.stdout, "\r\n");
    return lib_dir;
}

fn detectWasmerIncludeDir(b: *std.build.Builder) ?[]const u8 {
    const argv = &[_][]const u8{ "wasmer", "config", "--includedir" };
    const result = std.ChildProcess.run(.{
        .allocator = b.allocator,
        .argv = argv,
    }) catch return null;

    if (result.stderr.len != 0 or result.term.Exited != 0) return null;

    const lib_dir = std.mem.trimRight(u8, result.stdout, "\r\n");
    return lib_dir;
}
```

EDIT: I didn't solve this issue but found that using WasmEdge just worked, so doing that: https://github.com/WasmEdge/WasmEdge